# #PHPUnit Testing simple Code in this Link:https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-8.html

Tags: phpunit

Hello I am new in PHPUnit and  try to execute the Test Example:EmailTest by Composer, the Link is: https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-8.html

I got the text in the command_Line

```
$ phpunit --bootstrap vendor/autoload.php tests/EmailTest
PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Cannot open file "vendor/autoload.php".
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have different installations of PHPUnit mixed up.

For instance, you may have used Composer to install PHPUnit and have configured the autoloader generated by Composer as PHPUnit's bootstrap script but then you invoke PHPUnit using an executable other than `vendor/bin/phpunit`.